# A word describing the fact that a technology has become commonplace

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, technology

I'm looking for this word which is often associated with a technology going from specialist only, to being available for everyone. For instance, this word could be used to describe computers, the internet, or even simply phones.

I can't exactly remember if it's a single word (pretty sure it is though) or a short idiom, but I know it's commonly used.

Comment: "mainstream"? I'm seeing a lot of Google hits for everything from DVDs and Blu-Rays to musical artists and foods.

Comment: Something becomes a **household appliance**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word I was looking for is "Democratisation" (or "Democratization" for the fellows on the other side of the Atlantic), which is defined as

> the action of making something accessible to everyone.

by the Oxford dictionary.

I hope this answer will help people in the future!

Comment: Ubiquitous could also be used to describe it the product after some catalyst democratized it.